# How do I define a composite key in Persistent

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

How do I declare to Persistent that I have a table the primary key of which is a combination of two fields?

For example, assume I have a table containing first_name and last_name, then in SQL syntax I'll need something like:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (first_name,last_name)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Primary <field1> <field2>` syntax as per code below.

```
PrimaryCompositeWithOtherNullableFields
    foo String       maxlen=20
    bar String       maxlen=20
    baz String Maybe
    Primary foo bar   -- THIS LINE --
    deriving Eq Show
    enter code here
```

The above code is taken from one of the tests at https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/persistent-test/src/CompositeTest.hs#L74

[This wiki page](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax) explains the different syntax for defining the model in persistent. It really should have been part of the Yesod book.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent, section Uniqueness

```
Person
    firstName String
    lastName String
    age Int
    PersonName firstName lastName
    deriving Show
```

This define a unique key made of both firstName and lastName.

Comment: By default there is a integer id field that is the primary key and used internally. Why do you need a specific primary key? If really you do, I don't think you can do it using vanilla Persistent, you may have to code the table yourself.

Comment: I'm using an existing table that is shared with existing applications... It seems as if I'll need to overcome this with some workaround then.

Comment: You might be interested in Groundhog. Many parts of its API are similar to Persistent, but it has some extra features including the composite keys. This example https://github.com/lykahb/groundhog/blob/master/examples/keys.hs shows one-column natural keys, but it is easy to make them composite if you add more columns to the unique constraints.